# Terminal emulator crashes with function with nested case statements?

Tags: bash, shell, function

This function essentially aims:

```
alias "git log"="git log --name-status"
```

had it been possible. Since it is not possible to alias something with spaces in it, I choose to write a shell function:

```
git() {
        case $# in
        1)
                case "$1" in
                log)
                        git log --name-status
                ;;
                *)
                        git "$@"
                ;;
                esac
        ;;
        *)
                git "$@"
        ;;
        esac
}
```

However, whenever I run this, the terminal emulator crashes after ~1 second.

What might be the reason for this?

I am using mintty and Cygwin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're recursively calling `git` the function. Use `command git` for the internal calls so that the function isn't used for them.